# What is causing `delete-trailing-whitespace`?

Tags: whitespace, deletion

In some buffers (e.g. `diff` buffers) the trailing whitespace is essential to the format and must be preserved. What is causing Emacs to invoke `delete-trailing-whitespace` whenever I save the buffer?

- The `before-save-hook` contains only `(time-stamp)`, which doesn't alter trailing white space.
- The variables `write-contents-functions`, `write-file-functions`, `local-write-file-hooks` all have the value `nil`.
- The active minor modes are, according to `describe-mode`:

  Async-Bytecomp-Package Auto-Composition
  Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Auto-Revert Column-Number
  Diff-Auto-Refine File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Eldoc
  Global-Font-Lock Global-Git-Commit Line-Number Magit-Auto-Revert
  Midnight Mouse-Wheel Projectile Projectile-Global Shell-Dirtrack
  Tool-Bar Tooltip Transient-Mark

  None of those have any obvious behaviour to remove trailing whitespace on save.
- This unwanted behaviour still happens even when I manually set `fundamental` mode in the buffer.

The backtrace when the `delete-trailing-whitespace` function gets called looks like:

```
* delete-trailing-whitespace()
* run-hook-with-args-until-success(delete-trailing-whitespace)
* basic-save-buffer(t)
```

I haven't asked for `delete-trailing-whitespace`, it's not in any relevant hooks that I can find, yet `run-hook-with-args-until-success` is being told to run it. Why?

Comment: Does it happen when you start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`)?  If not, recursively bisect your init file until you isolate the code that deals with the whitespace.

Comment: What @Dan said. Or `M-x debug-on-entry save-buffers-kill-terminal` and step through the debugger to see why it happens.

Comment: The functions hooked into `before-save-buffer` are not called by `run-hook-with-args-until-success` but the functions in the following hooks are: `write-contents-functions`, `local-write-file-hooks`, and `write-file-functions`. Furthermore, there is a discussion to use `delete-trailing-whitespace` for git there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591923/make-git-automatically-remove-trailing-whitespace-before-committing and there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164292/my-emacs-deletes-trailing-white-space-how-can-i-disable-this-behaviour using `write-file-functions`. Search for that!